# Minimizing movie creation time in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, runtime, movie, minimization

I am using MATLAB's `movie()` function to make a movie of a large amount of time series data. With its current instantiation, it will take about 14 hours to finish. What can I do to better optimize it?

The biggest thing I am trying to do is suppress drawing the plot to the screen each time while still updating it for the getframe() function.

An abbreviated version of my code is:

```
t = 0:1000000; % I have about 10^6 data points
x = sin(t); % Let's pretend the data I'm plotting is the sine function
y = cos(t); % I have multiple data series being plotted in 'snapshots'
num_frames = length(t);
movie_length = 100; % seconds
fps = 60;
for k = 1:num_frames
clf; hold on;
plot(1, x(k),'bo')
plot(2, y(k),'bo')

ax = gca;
ax.XLim = [0 1];
ax.YLim = [-1,1];

f(k) = getframe;
end

movie(f,1,fps)
```

Comment: I don't know if the numbers are just examples, but 10^6 in 100 s is far beyond the [flicker fusion threshold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold). If you just want to show a movie, you can safely reduce the number of images by a factor of 100. That would not speed up generating a single image, but the total movie.

Comment: 10^6 is an approximate place holder value for the real value, but I want to record each data point. I thus changed the code above to hard code in 60 fps. At 60 fps, that's a long video, so I may cut down the data points that I record. Regardless, this process will still take a while. How can I better optimize the computation time?

Comment: I suggest using the profiler to see whether there are any bottlenecks in your code.  Also, if you call plot multiple times per frame, you may be able to speed things up if you can combine them into a single call.  (Put nan values in to separate different series.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one version which speeds it up by approximatly a factor of two on my machine. I have reduced the number of points to `10^3`.

```
clear f g; 
t = 0:10^3; % I have about 10^6 data points
x = sin(t); % Let's pretend the data I'm plotting is the sine function
y = cos(t); % I have multiple data series being plotted in 'snapshots'
num_frames = length(t);



tic;
for k = 1:num_frames
    clf; hold on;
    plot(1, x(k),'bo')
    plot(2, y(k),'bo')

    ax = gca;
    ax.XLim = [.8  2.2];
    ax.YLim = [-1,1];

    f(k) = getframe();

end
toc

% This is faster

h_fig = figure;

g(num_frames) = struct('cdata', [], 'colormap', []);
tic;
ax = axes(h_fig);
ax.XLim = [.8 2.2];
ax.YLim = [-1,1];
hold on;
p1 = plot(1,x(1), 'bo');
p2 = plot(2,y(1), 'bo');
drawnow;
g(1) = getframe(ax);
for k = 2:num_frames
    p1.YData = x(k);
    p2.YData = y(k);
    g(k) = getframe(ax);
end

toc
```

Note that without `getframe`, the second version is about 100 times faster. thus, If you know how to compute the `cdata` of a single frame, it might be much faster than to plot the data and use `getframe`.

One remark: I was not able to copy&paste&run your code without errors. Even if written quickly from mind, it would be nice if you could test it for errors before posting.